# Manually deleted package in External Libraries/Dart Packages not reappearring (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart-pub, dart-packages

I manually deleted a package in **External libraries/dart packages**. Now I tried to run `packages get` again. The package(tesseract_ocr) did not appear in **External libraries/dart packages**.
I tried removing it in pubspec.yaml and re-adding it but did not appear again. I tried deleting *.pub-cache* and run `packages get` again. I tried `flutter clean`, `flutter pub cache repair`, `flutter pub cache add tessarect_ocr` and `packages get` so many times but none of them made *tessarect_ocr* package reappear in **External libraries/dart packages**. Please Help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
dart pub cache clean
```

or

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

facing the same issue I did the following things:
1.

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

which reinstalled all the packages
2. `

> flutter pub get

`
which update the dependencies and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I went to C:\Users\kk\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev
and deleted the file of package which was not in the packages list.

note: C:\Users\kk, here in my case "kk" is written, in your case it will be name of your pc.

Then click on the "pub get" after putting package name in pubspec.yaml folder under dependencies.
*Make sure that your internet is working.

Now, go and check the packages list, you will see the package installed there.

Comment: If there are commands that do what you said to do manually (delete files in a specific folder), you should prefer that. Why do you think "flutter pub cache clean" is not OK in this case?